# Regular expression to extract number with sign between quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using Unity 5.3.4 and using C#. I was wondering if it would be possible to extract with regular expressions the value in this string, I do need the sign, as now is negative but it doesn't have to be that way:

```
string str = " "rssi": "-56", "
```

I do know that to use regular expression in unity it would be this way:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "*regular expression*", String.Empty);
```

I was wondering what would be a proper regular expression. I've been trying some in http://www.regexr.com/ But with no luck. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regular expresstion :`[-+]?\d+`

Meaning: get the one or more digits may be followed by sign.

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/aE2aR7/2)

Comment: I would also add an escape character to the `-` for good practice. i.e. `[\-+]`. It makes little difference in this case, but if more characters are added, there is a risk of the regex breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution:

```
Regex rgxNumber = new Regex("([-+]{0,1}[0-9]+)");
Match mNumber = rgxNumber.Match(str);

string result = mNumber.Groups[1].Value;
```

Hope it helps someone else.